# How do i stream a video with openCV into my pytorch neural network?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

I wrote YOLOv3 in Pytorch from scratch. If i send an image through the model with trained weights, it kinda works. Next step is to use my camera to make YOLO do its magic in real time.

I think the correct working pipeline is to catch a single frame of the video and feed it to the network. Than, write the boxes on the very same frame.

```
checkpoint = torch.load("\my_checkpoint_40.pth.tar")
model = YOLOv3(in_channels = 3, num_classes = 20).to(config.DEVICE)
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint["state_dict"])
ip_camera = "http://192.168.1.70:4500/mjpegfeed?640x480"
outputFile = "yolo_out_py.avi"
```

In this way, i load the weights into the net. Then, i wrote the function to use my camera (it's droidCamera from my mobile, because on my PC i have not any camera device, so i use the ip of the mobile device) and the code itself works: the video appears on screen.
The outputFile should be the destination path of the wrote video.
Problems are when i try to load a single frame into the net and do the rest of the process.

```
def streaming(model, thresh, iou_thresh, anchors, ip_camera):
    stream = cv2.VideoCapture(ip_camera)

    # Corrective actions printed in the even of failed connection.
    if stream.isOpened() is not True:
        print('Not opened.')
        print('Please ensure the following:')
        print('1. DroidCam is not running in your browser.')
        print('2. The IP address given is correct.')
    # Resizing the image to be in hte same dimension of the YOLOv3 Network
    width = 416
    height = 416
    # Connection successful. Proceeding to display video stream.
    while stream.isOpened() is True:
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, f = stream.read()
        dim = (width, height)
        image = cv2.resize(f, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        cv2.imshow('frame', image)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        for frame in image:
            model.eval()
            anchors = torch.tensor(anchors)
            anchors = anchors.to(config.DEVICE) 
            x = torch.tensor(frame)
            x = x.to("cuda")

           # from this line to the nms_boxes, it's the same code i used for plotting a single               image
            with torch.no_grad():
                out = model(x)
                bboxes = [[] for _ in range(x.shape[0])]
                for i in range(1):
                    batch_size, A, S, _, _ = out[i].shape
                    anchor = anchors[i]
                    boxes_scale_i = cells_to_bboxes(
                        out[i], anchor, S = S, is_preds = True
                    )
                    for idx, (box) in enumerate(boxes_scale_i):
                        bboxes[idx] += box

                model.train()

            for i in range(batch_size):
                nms_boxes = non_max_suppression(
                    bboxes[i], iou_threshold = iou_thresh, threshold = thresh, box_format =                   "midpoint",
                )
           # cells_to_boxes and non_max_suppression are functions that return boxes coordinates
           # and the "better" box

                #now it's time to write things on the frame
                frame = cv2.VideoWriter(outputFile, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 30,
                                        (round(stream.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)), round(stream.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))))

                frame.write(nms_boxes)
    stream.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the code doesn't work for several reasons: model.eval() gives me an error: missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

then, i have several errors that i think are about the right pipiline of work on stream of video. It's the first time i work with openCV.

If i delete model.eval(), i have another error on:

```
out = model(x)
```

This is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python_Project/YOLOV3/openVid.py", line 97, in <module>
    streaming(YOLOv3, 0.6, 0.6, config.ANCHORS, ip_camera)
  File "C:/Python_Project/YOLOV3/openVid.py", line 72, in streaming
    out = model(x)
  File "C:\Python_Project\YOLOV3\model.py", line 106, in __init__
    self.layers = self.create_conv_layers()
  File "C:\Python_Project\YOLOV3\model.py", line 141, in create_conv_layers
    CNNBlock(
  File "C:\Python_Project\YOLOV3\model.py", line 46, in __init__
    self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, bias = not bn_act, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Simone\anaconda3\envs\Pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 430, in __init__
    super(Conv2d, self).__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Simone\anaconda3\envs\Pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 83, in __init__
    if in_channels % groups != 0:
RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous
```

I have no clue about what doing next.
I saw i should convert the model in ONNX, but i really don't know what to do. I couldn't find any tutorial on internet, and i'm stucked.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message, `model` is not a class instance. Note, in the Traceback, that

```py
out = model(x)
```

is calling the `__init__` function. Therefore, `model` is probably `YOLOV3` rather than `YOLOV3(...)`. Based on the init signature, `x` is being taken as `in_channels`, and as `x` an image, the

> RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous

makes sense. This also explains the `.eval()` error. Besides that, I believe you'll need to add a batch dimension to your frame (e.g., `x.unsqueeze(0)`), otherwise you'll get another error.

Comment: You have right, now it works till the part where i create the writer. Point is, from there, do i have to use the
 .write()
in order to draw on the current frame?
Or it only works to save a new file?

Comment: @SimoneDeBellis glad it helped! That`.write()` call writes the next frame to the output file... passing `nms_boxes` shouldn't work. If you want to draw on the frame, you should use some other function (if available on your code) or implement one on your own.